# When is a polynomial map over the complex plane proper?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am trying to prove the following for a polynomial map $p$:

$p:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is proper $\iff$ $p$ is non-constant

How would I go about doing this, with definitions alone? With the first assumption we can get that if $p$ were constant then the mapping doesn't necessarily send compact sets to compact sets, but I'm not quite sure on how to go about proving the other direction, that if $p$ is non-constant then the map is proper.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You want *preimages* of compact sets to be compact. A compact set (in the complex plane) is closed and bounded. Can a preimage of a bounded set be unbounded? (hint: what happens to polynomials at infinity?) Similarly for closed (hint: take subsequences).